# WorkManager: Why does failed unique work with the "APPEND" ExistingWork strategy not allow more work under the same name?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Let's say we are developing a messaging app where we want to send messages into given conversations where the order of those messages is important in that conversation only, and if the app is put to the background, we want a guarantee that the message will be sent.

The `WorkManager#beginUniqueWork` method seems ideal for this, where the `uniqueWorkName` will be some conversation id, and `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND` will be used as the work policy to keep the work in the order scheduled.

So far in my application, as long as each piece of Work returns `Result.SUCCESS`, then any future scheduled work will be executed as expected. However, if one particular message fails to send in a fatal way and I return `Result.FAILURE`, then all future work with the same conversation id never seems to reach my implementation of `Worker#doWork()`.

After digging through the source code of the `EnqueueRunnable` class, this seems like a very deliberate choice. What I can't really understand is why that is? It seems odd that if a `uniqueWorkName` fails, that that name becomes unusable for the rest of the life of the application (this persists across killing the app).

Furthermore, I'd like to know if anybody has a good solution to this, or knows if this will change in future versions of `WorkManager`. So far, the best thing I can think of is to return `Result.SUCCESS` but encode my own failure state in the output `Data` so that any observers of the work know it has failed. This however is a bit awkward and isn't very obvious for future maintainers of the code (and can be a bit confusing when watching the logs for a given piece of `Work`).

Perhaps my intended use of unique work is completely wrong and there's a better solution out there. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to answer without a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve. As you have seen, returning [Result.FAILURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.Result)  has the effect that any work that depends on this will also be marked as failed and will not be run. The idea is that a FAILURE indicates to WorkManager that nothing more can be done in this chain. Another way to see it, is that this return value is used to indicate to WorkManager what to do next (SUCCESS => continue, FAILURE => stop, RETRY => re-run the current worker).

Comment: @pfmaggi that all makes perfect sense for a chain of work where the dependencies were mapped out before enqueueing the chain, but here I'm talking about uniqueWork, and in particular that if one piece of unique work fails, that all future work posted to that same name will never be scheduled, even if at the time of posting the latest piece of uniqueWork, there was no work currently being executed. 

Basically once failed, that particular `uniqueWorkName` becomes unusable for the rest of the life of the app, which to me was unexpected.

Comment: @pfmaggi And thanks for the feedback, which part of what I'm trying to achieve was unclear? I tried to describe that in the first 2 paragraphs, but if you think something is missing I'll add more info

Comment: Re-read your first two paragraphs and it makes sense. But then again, if you cannot send one of the message in the chain, what do you want to do? just send the others (with a missing message) or retry it? Personally, I think that the best option would be to retry sending the "failed" message. In which cases are you returning a failure?

Comment: One particular example would be if we've been trying to send the message for too long, then we might want to fail sending it and report this to the user, so then they can decide if we should retry (perhaps the message is now out of date). As I mentioned, for now I'm just returning `Result.SUCCESS` and putting some failure codes in the output `Data`, but now I literally never want to call `Result.FAILURE`, or else that conversation becomes unusable, which just seems odd to me!

Comment: If you think that this is a problem of the WorkManager library, please open a bug on the [WorkManager public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197) or add a feature request. I'll see to prioritize it.

Comment: @pfmaggi, great thank you, will do

Comment: @pfmaggi, actually, looking through the issue tracker, I found that this is intended behaviour and won't be fixed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111621980. 
In fact, they even suggested to do what I'm now doing by returning `SUCCEED`. I guess that answers my question then...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I found the answer to my own question in [this google issue tracker report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111621980).

Basically, unique work using the `APPEND` strategy creates a `WorkContinuation` where every new item is chained on as if we were to use the `WorkContinuation#then` method. Failing or cancelling the chain then cancels all downstream work, and so this is intended behaviour.

The ticket suggests 2 approaches:

> If you really want APPEND's behavior, then another thing you could do is to check for WorkStatuses of the WorkRequests, and if (all of them happened to be cancelled) use REPLACE instead of APPEND. Bear in mind, this is inherently racy, because your WorkRequests might not have cancelled yet. So make sure you have some synchronization primitives around your use of WorkManager's APIs.

and

> The simplest way to do this is to not actually return Result.FAILED; if you always return SUCCEEDED and return the actual pass/fail bit (if needed) in the output data, you can make sure the chain always keeps running.

Which is what I'm already doing. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Returning Result.success() in every case indeed did the trick. I personnaly use EventBus to post any previous result. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

Important update regarding that matter:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy#append_or_replace

> APPEND_OR_REPLACE
>
> enum val APPEND_OR_REPLACE : ExistingWorkPolicy
>
> If
> there is existing pending (uncompleted) work with the same unique
> name, append the newly-specified work as the child of all the leaves
> of that work sequence. Otherwise, insert the newly-specified work as
> the start of a new sequence.
>
> **Note:** If there are failed or cancelled
> prerequisites, these prerequisites are dropped and the newly-specified
> work is the start of a new sequence.

That's probably the team's response to exactly this issue. This new `ExistingWorkPolicy` is available in version `2.4.0-alpha01`.

**EDIT AFTER FURTHER TESTING...**

So it turns out the only thing this fixes is not being able to reuse the `UniqueWorkContinuation` if for some reason it failed once. However, the main feature, e.g. being able to cancel a single `WorkChain` when many `Workchains` are queues with the same unique name still doesn't work. Typically, consider: `WorkChainA` with `CompressWorkerA` and `UploadWorkerA` and then queuing `WorkChainB` with `CompressWorkerB` and `UploadWorkerB`, all under the same `UniqueWorkName`. Canceling or failing any `Worker` in `WorkChainA` will cause `WorkChainB` never to run... Thus we still have to make sure to return `Result.success()` every time. And don't use any `cancelWorkByTag` or `cancelWorkById` withing the `UniqueWork`!

Answer (score 1):

Stacked with the same, thanks for your investigation on this problem.

After playing a while to find best solution, currently this one works for me

```
startUpload() {

   workManager.pruneWork()
   //Prunes all eligible finished work from the internal database.

   photoAdapter.data.forEach {
      val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<FileUploadWorker>()
            .setInputData(workDataOf(IMAGE_PATH_PROP to it.path))
            .addTag(UPLOADER_TAG)
            .build()

      workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_TAG, ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, workRequest)
   }
}
```

calling "**pruneWork**" makes it to forget about cancelled or failed works.
But, I guess, this solution might have **caveats** so be carefull.

Another idea can look like this:

```
workManager.getWorkInfosForUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_TAG).get().forEach {

            if ( it.state == WorkInfo.State.FAILED || it.state == WorkInfo.State.CANCELLED) {
                //Redefine your UNIQUE_WORK_TAG
                UNIQUE_WORK_TAG = UUID().toString()
                return
            }
        }
```

try to find failed WorkInfo's and "switch" to new unique work tag.
Better aproaches appreciated.

p.s. "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.4" does't have new ExistingWorkPolicy apart from (KEEP,REPLACE,APPEND)